# What's the correct way of setting focus-events option in tmux.conf?

Tags: tmux

I'm using the following configuration line in tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g focus-events on
```

but tmux returns the following error while starting up:

```
/home/username/.xdg/config/tmux.conf:9: unknown command: set-option -g focus-events on
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to run `tmux.conf` as a shell script?

Comment: That error messages is similar to the way the `zsh` shell would report error if it was used to run the configuration file, but it would only complain about the command name, not the whole line.  Did you put the line in quotes in the configuration file? Could you possibly include the file in the question?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to run it as a shell script.

Comment: Sorry about the noise, I had a typo (an underscore between the option command).  Thanks anyway!

Comment: There is no underscore in the text of your question. Should we assume that the issue has been resolved?

Comment: Yes, it was resolved.  Thank you.